# Использование библиотеки Siren для управления обновлением приложения

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appstore

Всем привет, пытаюсь настроить контроль загрузки обновлений для своего приложения, для этого использую данную библиотеку
https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

В связи с тем что моего приложения еще нет в App Store пытаюсь идти по этому пути:

> If you currently don't have an app in the store, change your bundleID to one that is already in the store. In the sample app packaged with this library, we use the App Store Connect app's bundleID: com.apple.AppStoreConnect.

но получаю ошибку что такой id не может быть зарегистрирован, сталкивался ли кто с подобной проблемой? и если да, то как удалось решить?

Answer (score 0):

В xcode идем в настройки проекта -> Info. Здесь меняем "Bundle identifier" (например на ru.yandex.mobile.search).